# React frontend routing beyond / does not work on production build to express server

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, routes

I have a React + Express project that looks like this:

```
+  frontend/
    _  build/
    _  public/
    _  src/
    _  package.json
    _ ...
+  server/
    _  index.ts
-  package.json
- ...
```

In my client, I use a React Router:

**index.tsx**:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
  );
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />}/>
          <Route path="~" element={<MainPanel/>}>
            <Route path="profile" element={<Profile/>}/>
            <Route path="feed" element={<Feed/>}/>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
```

I also set up the nodejs express server as a proxy in the frontend
in **client/package.json**:

```js
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    // ...
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001" // 
}
```

Everything runs fine in dev! After running `npm run build`, I serve my frontend with my nodejs express server as follows:

**server/index.ts**

```js
import express, {Express, Request, Response, urlencoded} from "express";

const PORT : any = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app : Express = express();


app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`);
})

app.use('/', express.static('client/build'))
```

What ends up happening: I am able to enter the first route `/` of the app. But if I went to any further routes e.g. `/~/profile` or `/~/feed` I get `cannot GET /~/profile` or `cannot GET /~/feed`

How can I host a react app, that uses frontend routing, with a nodejs express server?

Comment: You have to redirect every 404 to `index.html`. That's how every react server works, that's why you can have frontend routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up server [Server Side Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually/36623117#36623117) as well as client side. React-Router is client side rendering. This link has an extremely well put answer to the question React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually. You have to set it up in two places for the BrowserRouter to work correctly.

An option to avoid this is to use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter. HashRouter will look like `https://www.website.com/#/FAQ` Everything after the hash will not be sent to the server. So the server will only see `https://www.website.com/` then react router will pick up the rest of the url and populate the page from there.

Comment: Ah thanks, it looked like I got this working by adding `app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "client", "build", "index.html"))
})` to my server